# R: remove rows with a combination of text conditions in 2 columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove the rows of a data frame that meet certain conditions based on 2 columns:

1. contain `_text1` in `Column1`
2. don't have `text2` exact match in `Column2`

I've managed to find a way to filter the rows I want to remove with the below code:

```
Table%>%filter(str_detect(Column1, '_text1') & Column2!="text2")
```

but I can't think of a way to reverse the code in order give me back the rows I want to keep, by simultaneously satisfying both conditions.

Comment: You can use `!` to negate the expression (if that's what you're trying to do, your question is a bit unclear): `Table%>%filter(! (str_detect(Column1, '_text1') & Column2!="text2") )`

Comment: Thanks! Nesting both conditions !(conditions) did the trick. I wasn't aware this was possible to do. Thank you so much !!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test my answer because you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but, if I understood you correctly, you can simply negate your condition:

```
Table%>%filter(!(str_detect(Column1, '_text1') & Column2!="text2"))
```